# Find gap between date ranges with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I found two queries on explainextended.com which helps me flatting a series of date ranges and getting the gaps between them (find the missing date ranges). The queries are [this](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/13/flattening-timespans-mysql/) and [this](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/12/inverting-date-ranges-mysql/). They both work, however the last one works on non-overlapping ranges. This is why I need a way to merge the two queries into one. How can I do it?

**Sample data**

```
date        start           stop
2009.06.03  05:54:48:000    10:00:13:000
2009.06.03  09:26:45:000    09:59:40:000
```

**Flatted data**

```
date        start           stop
2009.06.03  05:54:48:000    10:00:13:000
```

**Gaps**

```
start                    end
NULL                     2009.06.03 05:54:48:000
2009.06.03 10:00:13:000  NULL
```

**Inverting date ranges**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  @startdate AS _startdate,
            (
            SELECT  enddate
            FROM    t_range rp
            WHERE   rp.startdate = _startdate
            ) AS e,
            @startdate := startdate AS s
    FROM    (
            SELECT  @startdate := CAST(NULL AS DATETIME)
            ) vars,
            t_range
    ORDER BY
            startdate
    ) q
UNION ALL
SELECT  @startdate AS _startdate,
    (
    SELECT  enddate
    FROM    t_range rp
    WHERE   rp.startdate = _startdate
    ),
    NULL
```

**Flattening timespans**

```
SELECT  MIN(s_start) AS r_start, MAX(s_stop) AS r_stop
FROM    (
    SELECT  s_start,
            s_stop,
            @r := @r + (s_start > @edate) AS r_num,
            @edate := GREATEST(@edate, s_stop)
    FROM    (
            SELECT  @r := 0,
                    @edate := '0001-01-01'
            ) vars,
            t_span
    ORDER BY
            s_start
    ) q
GROUP BY
    r_num
```

**Link to sample sqlFiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd1d2/7

**Test query by me**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   
    SELECT  @startdate AS _startdate,
            (
            SELECT  s_end
            FROM    (
                SELECT  MIN(s_start) AS s_start, MAX(s_end) AS s_end
                FROM    (
                    SELECT  s_start,
                    s_end,
                    @r := @r + (s_start > @edate) AS r_num,
                    @edate := GREATEST(@edate, s_end)
                    FROM    (
                        SELECT  @r := 0,
                        @edate := '0001-01-01'
                    ) vars,
                    t_span
                    ORDER BY
                    s_start
                ) q
                GROUP BY
                r_num                   
            ) rp
            WHERE   rp.s_start = _startdate
            ) AS e,
            @startdate := s_start AS s
    FROM    (
            SELECT  @startdate := CAST(NULL AS DATETIME)
            ) vars,
            (
                SELECT  MIN(s_start) AS s_start, MAX(s_end) AS s_end
                FROM    (
                    SELECT  s_start,
                    s_end,
                    @r := @r + (s_start > @edate) AS r_num,
                    @edate := GREATEST(@edate, s_end)
                    FROM    (
                        SELECT  @r := 0,
                        @edate := '0001-01-01'
                    ) vars,
                    t_span
                    ORDER BY
                    s_start
                ) q
                GROUP BY
                r_num       
            ) test
    ORDER BY
            s_start
    ) q
UNION ALL
SELECT  @startdate AS _startdate,
    (
    SELECT  s_end
    FROM    t_span rp
    WHERE   rp.s_start = _startdate
    ),
    NULL
```

Comment: You should post your code here. If the links disappear your question has no meaning.

Comment: Please post the queries in your question, not just as links. And show what you've tried to solve your problem, we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Quassnoi

Comment: Could the overlapping ranges be ignored or they are important?

Comment: I added the two queries. Overlapping ranges can't be ignored, I have to flat all the ranges before trying to get the gaps. I'm a newbie, so I don't know how to start to merge the two queries. This is why I'm asking help here

Comment: I'd suggest you post sample data, preferably in a form of [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and the desired outcome

Comment: @Quassnoi as you're the author of the queries can you help me out?

Comment: @Barmar I did my homework and tried to merge the two queries. It seems to work but I don't think the overall query is optimized and I would like to get some hints if it's correct as I wrote it or if there are hidden bugs due to my merge

Comment: These types of queries are not very optimizable. The nature of what it's doing requires a sequential scan.

Comment: sure but for optimization I was looking at the merged queries which does the same thing twice. Maybe there is a way to just run that query one time and use the result twice